# C - Nested For loop never stops

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops

I wrote a simple nested For loop, but for some reason it never stops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int x,y;

    for (x=10;x<100;x+=10) {
        for (y=10;y<100;x+=10)
            printf("x is %d \n",x);
            printf("y is %d \n",y);
    }
return 0;
}
```

I'm new at c, but from examples I read, it should stop when x and y gets to 100. But for some reason it keeps on going for ever.

Comment: Whenever you copy, paste, and modify, triple-check your work. And ... the fact that it prints `y is 10` repeatedly is a major clue that should have spared you a trip to SO.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Too much c for today I guess. Thanks guys.

Comment: @JimBalter Wrong. He didn't see `y is 10` at all. This is because of the missing braces around the inner for loop. Look a little closer before chastising.

Comment: @slater Right you are. But that it just prints `x is 10`, `x is 20`, ad infinitum and never mentions y at all is a huge clue that  should have gotten the OP to bother to look at the code and avoid a foolish waste of time.

Comment: This is true. Coding requires a rigor of thought which is not the habit of beginners. IMO in some sense SO is not about coding help but thought help.

Answer (score 6):

You need to increment y, not x

```
for (y=10;y<100;y+=10)
```

Also, it really looks like you meant to put braces around the inner loop

```
for (y=10;y<100;y+=10) 
{  // <-- Did you mean to leave this out?

        printf("x is %d \n",x);
        printf("y is %d \n",y);

} // <-- and this?
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `y` is not updated in the loop, which will make the second `for` loop always true (i.e. run forever).

You need to change

```
for (y=10;y<100;x+=10)
                ^
           should be y here
```

to

```
for (y=10;y<100;y+=10)
```